# View just the "App" apps, without the games?

Tags: google-play-store

The Android Market / Play Store is structured with three main headings at the moment (at least in Australia, might be different elsewhere):

- Apps
- Games
- Books

However, when you delve into the "Apps" section, all the games are still present in the list, taking up an awful lot of the volume for something that has its own separate subcategory.

Is there a view of the market that does not include apps marked as "Games" in the "App" section?  Either in the on-phone version or a separate website.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of an app that shows just the non-game apps, but I thought I'd weigh in since you've not received any answers yet.

The best approach depends on what you're trying to accomplish. If you're looking for new apps to download, the featured apps are not often games (since they're covered in their own page). If you're browsing for apps, you could do it by category.